# What is the meaning of "Only hers were probably the real deal"?

Tags: meaning

On Julie's Birthday, Julie got pearl chain gift from her husband, Eric.
Julie loves Julia cooking books.

> Julie: Just like Julia's.
>
> Eric: **Only hers were probably the real deal**.

Comment: Please provide a source for this text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pearls are inexpensive, so they're probably artificial. *The real deal* means Julia Childs had real pearls. The term is slang for something genuine or, more recently, an outstanding example in a category.

I'm assuming the reference is to the movie *Julie and Julia* (2009), where the husband's name is Eric. By the way, the word "birthday" is not capitalized in normal usage, because it's not a proper noun.